# Gauge transformation issues of Proca Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

It seems to be trivial to claim that the mass term in Proca Lagrangian is NOT "gauge invariant". 
The claim show up in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proca_action)
or section 6.3 in Greiner's book "Field Quantization".
But I'm puzzled by this claim.
In my view, this **is** "gauge invariant" up to an surface term.

Let's do the "gauge transformation" by $V_\mu \to V_\mu +\partial_\mu \alpha$,
where $V_\mu$ is a vector field and $\alpha$ is a scalar field.
We then have
$$V^2 
\to (V^2+\partial_\mu\alpha\partial^\mu\alpha+2V_\mu \partial^\mu \alpha) 
\doteq (V^2-\alpha\partial^2\alpha - 2 \alpha \partial_\mu V^\mu)=V^2
$$
where in the $\doteq$ step, the surface term is dropped.
In the last step, I assume 
$$\partial^2\alpha=0,\partial_\mu V^\mu=0.$$

The above steps are totally reasonable to me. 
The only problematic assumption may be $\partial^2\alpha=0$.
Since on the prementioned Wikipedia's page, $\alpha$ is the most general one.

The reason I set $\partial^2\alpha=0$ is that we should always keep $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$, then if the initial vector field already fulfill this requirement, the degree of freedom to do the "gauge transformation" is quite constrained.
the scalar field should satisfy the equation $\partial^2\alpha=0$ right?

If we leave this question aside, I'm also confused by the use of terminology **gauge transformation** in the context of **massive** vectors.

**Should we really talk about gauge transformations of massive vectors?**

In the spirit of "gauge transformation = redundancy", I think we can, and the above transformation is fine, because it doesn't change the Lagrangian etc.
But I didn't see the claim like this show up anywhere, so there should be something wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The assumption you made: $\partial^2\alpha=0,\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ is nothing else but the Lorentz gauge fixing condition. See wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition

Comment: @MadMax Thanks. In the wiki page, it says, "It is equally used for massive spin-1 fields where the concept of gauge transformations does not apply at all. " Is it just a convention no to name the redundancy "gauge transformation"? Also is $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ a "natural" requirement of massive vectors or we can set it to be whatever value we want such as $\partial_\mu V^\mu=1.234$? (again I need some time to think about it.)

Comment: $\alpha$ can be _any_ scalar density. It can be, to give an absurd example, the mass density of a running elephant, a scalar wave function with is as a source. Your "reasonable" assumption do not do justice to the unreasonable character of an arbitrary gauge transformation.

Comment: In terms of gauge fixing, you don't have to set $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ as in Lorentz gauge. The $R_{\xi}$ gauge (see wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) is actually a generalization of the Lorentz gauge, which essentially treating $\partial_\mu V^\mu$ as Gausian distributed with zero mean and $\xi$ variance. Then, $\partial_\mu V^\mu=1.234$ is of course possible.

Comment: @MadMax Thanks for your explanation. Now I know where I was wrong.

Comment: Not Lorentz but Lorenz, of course.

Comment: @my2cts I think the logic is the following, $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ is automatically satisfied. We cannot apply the transformation $V_\mu \to V_\mu +\partial_\mu\alpha $ no matter what $\alpha$ is. One hand, $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ requires $\partial^2\alpha=0$, but on the other hand, the equation of motion is violated: we should have $(\partial^2+m^2)\partial_\mu\alpha=0$, but the l.h.s is $m^2\partial_\mu\alpha \ne 0$. That is to say, there are no degree of freedom to make a transformation at all.

Comment: I don't agree that $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$, but it does obey the homogeneous massive wave equation, so there is no or at most incomplete gauge invariance.

Comment: @my2cts The $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$ is a conclusion of the Lagrangian (apply $\partial$ to the equation of motion). There is also another way to check that the (complete or incomplete) gauge invariance doesn't exist. The physical degree of freedom of massive vector meson is $4-1=3$, where $-1$ comes from $\partial_\mu V^\mu=0$. However, for massless vector mesons, there is still a redundancy after applying the Lorenz gauge. namely $V_\mu \to V_\mu + \partial_\mu \alpha$, where $\partial^2\alpha=0$. This make the physical d.o.f=$4-1-1=2$. Exactly what we need.

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking of a slightly different equation.